# Usando WHERE com INNER JOIN

Tags: select, join

Existe uma jeito de usar um `WHERE`para fazer um `SELECT`com `INNER JOIN` ?

meu caso é este:

```sql
SELECT CodCli, NomeCli 
FROM tbvendas 
  INNER JOIN tbclientes 
  ON tbvendas.CodCli = tbclientes.AutoCod
```

Gostaria de colocar um `WHERE status = "debitado"`
sendo que a coluna `status` está na `tbvendas`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

pode adicionar a cláusula WHERE antes ou depois do Inner Join

```
SELECT CodCli, NomeCli 
FROM tbvendas 
    INNER JOIN tbclientes 
    ON tbvendas.CodCli = tbclientes.AutoCod
WHERE status = 'debitado'
```

para adicionar a cláusula WHERE na tbclientes, usa o AND depois da comparação ON

```
SELECT CodCli, NomeCli 
FROM tbvendas 
    INNER JOIN tbclientes 
    ON tbvendas.CodCli = tbclientes.AutoCod
    AND ...
WHERE status = 'debitado'
```

aí você pode filtrar tambem o conteúdo da tbclientes

Comment: É possível filtrar a `tbclientes` pelo `where` mesmo. O `AND` depois do `ON` é pra ser usado quando a condição **faz parte do Inner Join**.

Answer (score 6):

É só adicionar a clausúla `where` na consulta

```sql
SELECT CodCli, NomeCli 
FROM tbvendas 
  INNER JOIN tbclientes 
  ON tbvendas.CodCli = tbclientes.AutoCod    
Where Status = 'debitado'
```